# ListView Refresh is not working properly

Tags: c#, winforms

**Edit:** I've figured out why the texts are drawn as bold. Because OnDrawSubItem is called twice for the first column. Anyone knows why?

---

I have created a custom control inheriting from ListView class. I have overriden OnDrawSubItem and OnDrawItem methods as follows:

```
    protected override void OnDrawSubItem(DrawListViewSubItemEventArgs e)
    {
        Rectangle rowBounds = e.SubItem.Bounds;
        Rectangle labelBounds = e.Item.GetBounds(ItemBoundsPortion.Label);
        Rectangle bounds = new Rectangle(rowBounds.Left + 5, rowBounds.Top + 2, labelBounds.Width - 5, rowBounds.Height + 2);
        if (e.Item.Selected)
            e.Graphics.DrawString(e.SubItem.Text, Font, Brushes.White, bounds);
        else
            e.Graphics.DrawString(e.SubItem.Text, Font, Brushes.Black, bounds);

    }

    protected override void OnDrawItem(DrawListViewItemEventArgs e)
    {
        e.DrawBackground();
        if (e.Item.Selected)
        {
            Rectangle rowBounds = e.Bounds;
            Rectangle bounds = new Rectangle(0, rowBounds.Top, rowBounds.Width, rowBounds.Height);
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Gray, bounds);
        }
    }
```

But something's not working properly. When I add some items to the ListView, the texts are a bit thick. The listview is placed into a tab. When I switch to another tab and go back to the tab with listview, texts seems well. So I tried to make this and tried to add `listView.Refresh()` at the end of item adding operation, but it didn't work:

```
//code 1
foreach(string s in new string[] { "item1", "item2", "item3", "item4", "item5" })
{
    listView.Items.Add(s);
}
listView.Refresh();
```

Output is:

[image]

I also tried to refresh at each iteration, and it was a bit better, but the last element was not refreshed:

```
//code 2
foreach(string s in new string[] { "item1", "item2", "item3", "item4", "item5" })
{
    listView.Items.Add(s);
    listView.Refresh();
}
```

Output:

[image]

When the tab is switched, all texts are how they should be.

My two questions here:

1. Why are the texts rendered bad when they are added?
2. What is the difference between code 1 and code 2? I thought they should've worked the same way.

Also, maybe it is worth mentioning that if I add a second column, the second column is rendered well.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried calling [e.DrawBackground()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.drawlistviewitemeventargs.drawbackground%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) before DrawString? That may get rid of the thick text.

Comment: It removed the text when I click on something.